# Usage of Maps in Windows phone 8 without connecting to the network

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, bing-maps

I am working on a Windows 8 "phone" which for the following reasons is unable to use maps

1. Bing maps: Microsoft itself announced to not to support Bing maps APIs any further instead they'll be using Nokia APIs.
2. Nokia APIs: facing licensing issues.
3. In-built Map control: Network connectivity issues. the emulator is unable to connect to the network
4. Google APIs: It is only option left. But this again poses similar issues as I am naïve to its usage

Please suggest as to how can I use the Map functionality in my app without connecting to the network

Comment: what are the Nokia API licensing issues?  and Bing Maps are supported (deprecated != unsupported).

Comment: It is an organizational issue

Comment: Can I use Bing maps in windows phone 8 without connecting to the network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Bing maps are still supported they are just no longer the default. They are not as comprehensive as the Nokia datasets and have issues with being used in some parts of the world (China).
2. There are no licensing issues with using the embedded Nokia maps control in a Windows Phone 8 app. Why do you think there are licensing issues?
3. The built in Nokia maps control does support downloading maps for use offline. It's one of it's big selling points.
4. Google map tiles can bee used with the old/Bing maps control but does not provide automatic support for offline usage and it is a **LOT** of work to implement yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions
Can you help me navigate to a forum/page where I can find how to implement Bing Map APIs in my app
P.S. I cannot connect to network neither can I launch the in-built Map control